# Stuck trying to make a google forms script to email form answers

Tags: javascript, forms

first post here. I am trying to make a Google script that will allow me to send form responses to my email. Just plain simple text. I only need the form answer, nothing else, not even a subject. I am aware that there is a add-on for Forms that will do this, but it sends to much data.

Here is my code, it is giving up on line 8 saying:

> cannot find method sendEmail

```
function sendEmails(){
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm()
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();


  var emailAddress = 'myemailaddress@gmail.com';
  var body = formResponses;
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, body);

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The method you are calling with two parameters does not exist, try the following code by sending an email with a subject:

```
function sendEmails(){
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm()
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var emailAddress = 'myemailaddress@gmail.com';
  var subject = 'Insert Subject';
  var body = formResponses;
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, body);
}
```

Please see the the [Class MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) documentation, the following methods exist:

```
sendEmail(message)
sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)
sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)
sendEmail(to, replyTo, subject, body)
```